# How to create a List<int> basead on two properties from another list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

**Problem**

I need to create a `List<int>` basead on two properties from another list.

**Example**

I have a class that has two fields that I need.

```
public class MyClass
{
    //Other fields
    int? ValueId
    int? ValueTwoId
}
```

Above code it's an example, so do not focus there.

I want to retrieve those properties like:

```
myClassList.ElementAt(0).ValueId = 1;
myClassList.ElementAt(0).ValueTwoId = 2;
myClassList.ElementAt(1).ValueId = 3;
myClassList.ElementAt(1).ValueTwoId = 4;

List<int> resultList = myClassList.Where(x => x.ValueId != null && x.ValueTwoId != null).Select(x => ??).ToList());
```

**Desired Output**

```
resultList.ElementAt(0) == 1
resultList.ElementAt(1) == 2
resultList.ElementAt(2) == 3
resultList.ElementAt(3) == 4
```

There's a way to achieve this using `.Select(x => Something ).ToList()`, without using a code like:

```
List<int> resultList = new List<int>();

foreach(var item in myClassList)
{
   resultList.Add(item.ValueId);
   resultList.Add(item.ValueTwoId);
}
```

Thanks in advance, sorry my poor english.

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax, but you should look into C#'s `SelectMany()` function. I think it's exactly what you're looking for. See here: http://www.codethinked.com/a-visual-look-at-the-linq-selectmany-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
List<int> resultList = myClassList
    .Where(x => x.ValueId != null && x.ValueTwoId != null)
    .SelectMany(x => new List<int>{x.ValueId.Value, x.ValueTwoId.Value})
    .ToList();
```

As in:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClassList = new List<MyClass> {new MyClass(), new MyClass()};
            myClassList.ElementAt(0).ValueId = 1;
            myClassList.ElementAt(0).ValueTwoId = 2;
            myClassList.ElementAt(1).ValueId = 3;
            myClassList.ElementAt(1).ValueTwoId = 4;

            var resultList = myClassList
                .Where(x => x.ValueId != null && x.ValueTwoId != null)
                .SelectMany(x => new List<int> { x.ValueId.Value, x.ValueTwoId.Value})
                .ToList();

            foreach (var i in resultList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            //Prints out:
            //1
            //2
            //3
            //4
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            public int? ValueId;
            public int? ValueTwoId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from x in myClassList
             from sub in new[] { x.ValueId, x.ValueTwoId }
             where sub.HasValue
             select sub.Value;
```

It is not quite clear to me if you want to discard `x.ValueIdTwoId` just because `x.valueId` is `null`. If that is the case, use

```
var result = from x in myClassList
             from sub in new[] { x.ValueId, x.ValueTwoId }
             where x.ValueId.HasValue && x.ValueTwoId.HasValue
             select sub.Value;
```

instead.

As others have noted, what you need is LINQ's `SelectMany` operation. The `from` in the code samples above translate to `SelectMany`, as described in the remarks for the [Enumerable.SelectMany Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx).